# Animating using NumberAnimation and Behavior

Tags: qml

I'm trying to understand the functionality of **Behavior** by animating a small Rectangle when it's property changes. 
Consider the following example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    width: 600
    height: 80

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "red"
        width: 20
        height: 20

        property int xval: 0

        Behavior on xval {
            NumberAnimation {
                target: rect
                property: "x"
                to: rect.xval
                duration: 2000
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: { rect.xval=250 }
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to animate the **x** property of the Item **rect** on Button Click. But it doesnot animate. Now if you replace

```
to: rect.xval
```

with

```
to: 400
```

The Rectangle animates as expected on Button Click. All I want to do is to animate the Rectangle using the value set by the user. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a extra property to animate a property.
`Behavior on foo` will animate foo whenever it changes its value and make it the implicit property of inner Animations.
Your code can simply be

```
Item {
    width: 600
    height: 80

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "red"
        width: 20
        height: 20

        Behavior on x {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 2000
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: { rect.x=250 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems I got confused. Thanks for answer :)